# Pivoting Dataframe with Pandas

Tags: python, numpy, pandas

I have the below table taken online through `pandas.read_html`

```
      Column0    Column1      Column2      Column3
0     Entry_1    0.685        Record_1     0.69-S$ 0.685
1     Entry_2    0.036        Record_2     0.685
2     Entry_3    05/Jul/2016  Record_3     0.72-S$ 0.4
3     Entry_4    0.338        Record_4     178.8 mm
4     Entry_5    0.41         Record_5     0.06
5     Entry_6    122.48       Record_6     17.29%
6     Entry_7    0.5          Record_7     0.58 as of 05/Jul/2016
```

How do I pviot / transpose this data such that `Column 0` becomes the headers, and `Column 1` becomes the values. Similarly for `Column 2` and `Column 3`?

Comment: These are 2 dataframes? You want to merge them and then transpose the merged dataframe?

Comment: Nope. This is in 1 dataframe. This was the code I got when I printed the output from `pandas.read_html`. I want to make `Columns 0` and `Columns 2` the headers for the values in `Columns 1` and `Columns 3`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is probably the easiest way to solve this problem. The easiest way I could come up with anyway.

```
Column0     Column1     Column2     Column3
0   Entry_1     0.685   Record_1    0.69-S$ 0.685
1   Entry_2     0.036   Record_2    0.685
2   Entry_3     05/Jul/2016     Record_3    0.72-S$ 0.4
3   Entry_4     0.338   Record_4    178.8 mm
4   Entry_5     0.41    Record_5    0.06
5   Entry_6     122.48  Record_6    17.29%
6   Entry_7     0.5     Record_7    0.58 as of 05/Jul/2016

cols = df['Column0'].append(df['Column2'])
vals = df['Column1'].append(df['Column3'])

newdf = pd.DataFrame(vals).T
newdf.columns = cols
newdf



 Entry_1    Entry_2     Entry_3     Entry_4     Entry_5     Entry_6     Entry_7     Record_1    Record_2    Record_3    Record_4    Record_5    Record_6    Record_7
0   0.685   0.036   05/Jul/2016     0.338   0.41    122.48  0.5     0.69-S$ 0.685   0.685   0.72-S$ 0.4     178.8 mm    0.06    17.29%  0.58 as of 05/Jul/2016
```

Comment: Thanks Joe. This works :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use `lreshape` for create new columns, then [`set_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html) from `Col`, transpose by [`T`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.T.html) and last remove column name by [`rename_axis`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/whatsnew.html#changes-to-rename) (new in `pandas` `0.18.0`):

```
print (pd.lreshape(df, {'Col':['Column0', 'Column2'], 
                        0:['Column1', 'Column3']})
         .set_index('Col')
         .T
         .rename_axis(None, axis=1))

  Entry_1 Entry_2      Entry_3 Entry_4 Entry_5 Entry_6 Entry_7       Record_1  \
0   0.685   0.036  05/Jul/2016   0.338    0.41  122.48     0.5  0.69-S$ 0.685   

  Record_2     Record_3  Record_4 Record_5 Record_6                Record_7  
0    0.685  0.72-S$ 0.4  178.8 mm     0.06   17.29%  0.58 as of 05/Jul/2016
```

Comment: Thanks Jezrael! :)

Comment: If you want you can upvote ;-) Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you use the method [DataFrame.pivot](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.pivot.html) as the following example:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import pandas.util.testing as tm; tm.N = 3
def unpivot(frame):
    N, K = frame.shape
    data = {'value' : frame.values.ravel('F'),
            'variable' : np.asarray(frame.columns).repeat(N),
            'date' : np.tile(np.asarray(frame.index), K)}
    return pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['date', 'variable', 'value'])
df = unpivot(tm.makeTimeDataFrame())
print (df)

print (df.pivot(index='date', columns='variable', values='value'))
```

> **print(df)**:
>           date variable     value
>   0  2000-01-03        A  0.101495
>   1  2000-01-04        A -0.554863
>   2  2000-01-05        A -0.345271
>   3  2000-01-03        B -1.104909
>   4  2000-01-04        B -0.723819
>   5  2000-01-05        B  0.088401
>   6  2000-01-03        C  1.495768
>   7  2000-01-04        C -0.756166
>   8  2000-01-05        C -0.266072
>   9  2000-01-03        D  0.451050
>   10 2000-01-04        D -1.457763
>   11 2000-01-05        D  0.945552
>
> **print (df.pivot(index='date', columns='variable', values='value'))**:
>   variable           A         B         C         D
>   date                                              
>   2000-01-03  2.932572 -1.959961  0.385705 -1.629831
>   2000-01-04 -0.317548  0.031041  2.129526 -1.717546
>   2000-01-05  0.108186  1.182527  0.997716  0.453127

Comment: Hmm, so how should I be writing it from the data that I posted above? Quite new to this